# Inverse gaussian distribution c++

Tags: c++, statistics

I want to do a program in C++ that can get the inverse gaussian distribution of a number, like `NORM.S.INV` in Excel:

```
=NORM.S.INV(0.95) -> 1.644853627
```

I have tried using Boost, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/inverse_gaussian_dist.html

The problem is that I don't know how to use the boost package in order to do this. I tired do the program below:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/inverse_gaussian.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    using boost::math::inverse_gaussian;
    double Inverse = inverse_gaussian my_ig(2, 3);
    std::cout << Inverse;
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me `error: expected primary-expression before 'my_ig'`. Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Comment: `double Inverse = inverse_gaussian my_ig(2, 3);` -- What exactly are you trying to do with this line of code?

Comment: I want to assign the inverse (like in the Excel example) to a double.

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way, regardless of what you are trying to do.  The syntax doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Looks like that `inverse_gaussian` is not the same as `NORM.S.INV`, according to the documentation for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I think inverse_gaussian costructor can't return double...
For example this code work.

`inverse_gaussian my_ig(2, 3);
std::cout << my_ig.mean();`

Comment: I can compile that code, but it just returns the first of the values I put into the parentheses (in this case `2`).